# Chrome ffmpeg.js can not make a video more than 33 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, ffmpeg.js

I am encoding and exporting a video in mp4 and webm format. I am using ffmpeg.js. It works fine but i can not make a video longer than 33 seconds.

```
let ffmpegArguments:string[] = [];
ffmpegArguments.push("-framerate", (1.0/frameTime).toFixed(0),  "-i", "f%03d.jpg" , 
        "-loglevel", "debug", "-v", "verbose", "-c:v");
```

I tried to change `f%03d.jpg` with `f%04d.jpg` or `f%08d.jpg` but it stops. Any idea why?
Below console log is when i replace `f%03d.jpg` with `f%04d.jpg`
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyf0.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyf0.png

Comment: No errors? No log? No info?

Comment: For `f%04d.jpg` or `f%08d.jpg`  It says file not found....but also in chrome it does not show details in ffmpeg. It is affmpeg.js in browser.

Comment: Added a console log above.

Comment: Please copy and paste the console text instead of making an image of text. I had to manually go through all of your giant configure line without being able to quickly search and I can't copy text from it. `f%03d.jpg` expects `f001.jpg`, `f002.jpg`, `f003.jpg`, etc. `f%04d.jpg` expects `f0001.jpg`, and `f%08d.jpg` is looking for `f00000001.jpg`. What are your images named?

Comment: Images are named f001.jpg...f002.jpg....With the above code, i can not generate a video longer than 33 second. How to do that? The first 33 second video is fine.

Comment: My frame filename are created using : ```let fileName = "f" + i.toLocaleString([], {
                maximumFractionDigits:0,
                minimumIntegerDigits: 3,                   
            }) + ".jpg";```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using 8 digits instead of 3. And padding the digits.

```
        ffmpegArguments.push("-framerate", (1.0/frameTime).toFixed(0), "-i", "f%08d.jpg", "-c:v");
 let fileName = "f" + i.toString().padStart(8, '0') + ".jpg";
```